# how to send files with url in device in swift 3?

Tags: ios, post, swift3, nsfilemanager

I have a mini file manager in my app that user can copy files with iTunes - FileSharing into the app and then upload them to the server 
I used post Method But Didn't worked for me! I got the files url in the device But I don't know this way that I choose is right or not
here is the file detection codes

```
 // Get the document directory url
 let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
 do {
     // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
     let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
     print(directoryContents)

     // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
     let pdfFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }
     print("pdf urls:",pdfFiles)
     filesurl = pdfFiles
     print(pdfFiles.count)
     filesCount = pdfFiles.count
     let pdfFileNames = pdfFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
     print("pdf list:", pdfFileNames)
     filestext = pdfFileNames
 } catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

and here is the Url of files in the device

```
var names = String()
let rows = fileTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.map{$0.map{$0.row}}
print(rows!)

for i in rows! {
    print(filesurl[i])
    print(filestext[i])
    names.append("\(filestext[i])")
    fileManagerViewController.filesForUpload.append(filesurl[i])
}
```

and here is the post method that I used

```
let parameters = ["myfile" : "\(fileManagerViewController.filesForUpload)"]
print(parameters)
guard let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/api/file?api_token=\(EmailSignInViewController.api_token)") else {return}
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {return }
request.httpBody = httpBody

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data , response , error) in
    if let response = response {          
        print(response)
    }
    if let data = data {
        do {          
           let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])         
           print(json)
        } catch {           
           print(error)
        }
    }       
}.resume()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using uploadTask for uploading file data or doing POSTs? Search for Apple URL Session Programming Guide.

Comment: can you put a link here ? I couldn't find some thing that help me

Comment: This doc has both Obj-C and Swift examples, and it explains everything you need to know about URLSession.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1

Comment: I used the methods there and swift doesn't let me to run the app because of defaultSession as I told you I want to upload files that are exist in my device and I got the Url of files in my device and want to upload them with this url

Comment: Now look this question please I edited my question and asked it as a new question @u83six https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252271/convert-files-to-string-then-upload-them-in-swift-3